# How to check multiple range of condition in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formula, conditional-formatting

I need calculate salary details. I need to check multiple range of net salary.
If net salary range is between 6500-7500 then
Basic = 40 % of net salary

Same like I am having 4 ranges of net salary such as
6500- 7500,
7550 -8500,
8550-10500,
10550 and above

how to calculate this in excel

Comment: Sorry team I don't know why I am getting down votes.

Comment: I got my answer after little search. Actually new to excel, following is my formula tried of my own: =IF(AND(D2>6500,D2<7500),40,IF(AND(D2>7550,D2<8500),35,IF(AND(D2>8550,D2<10500),35,IF(AND(D2>10550,D2>10550),25,))))

Comment: You did not give all the information such as the 35% and 25% and you have two bands (7550-8500 and 8550-10500) at the same percentage : is that correct? Also, what happens to the results if the salary is 7525 or 8535 or 10545 ? Also, your last logical test is incorrect...

Comment: @ solar mike two bands having same percentage is correct. This will be given by company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

```
=IF(D2>10500,25,IF(D2>8500,35,IF(D2>7500,35,IF(D2>6500,40,"error"))))
```

Do note two of the bands have the same rate 35% - just wonder if one is meant to be 30%...

Comment: no those band are same and given by company. may those people have some other allowance